# Inject global variables in vue-components with webpack and style-resource-loader

Tags: vue.js, webpack, storybook

I've some global variables in `./src/assets/styles/_globals.scss`. Now I want to add them to all Vue-Components so I'm able to use variables within the scoped styles.

I'm using Gridsome for which this works fine with the following configuration:

```
const path = require('path')

function addStyleResource (rule) {
  rule.use('style-resource')
      .loader('style-resources-loader')
      .options({
        patterns: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets/styles/_globals.scss'),
        ],
      })
}

module.exports = {
  siteName: 'Gridsome',
  plugins: [],
  chainWebpack (config) {
    // Load variables for all vue-files
    const types = ['vue-modules', 'vue', 'normal-modules', 'normal']

    // or if you use scss
    types.forEach(type => {
      addStyleResource(config.module.rule('scss').oneOf(type))
    })
  }
}
```

Furthermore I'm using StoryBook to get a web-view with all my components. This is my configuration:

```
module.exports = async ({config, mode}) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets/styles/'),
    });

    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader', {
            loader: 'style-resources-loader',
            options: {
                patterns: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets/styles/_globals.scss'),
                ],
                type: ['vue-modules', 'vue', 'normal-modules', 'normal']
            }
        }],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets/styles/_globals.scss')
    });

    return config;
};
```

The configuration throws no error but used scss-variables within my scoped styles in my VueComponents could not be parsed/found.

How can I  publish those global styles to all my components?

My folder structure is this:

*
- .storybook
-- webpack.config.js
- src
-- assets
--- styles
---- _globals.scss
-- components
--- // All my Vue-Components

Comment: did you try [sass-resources-loader](https://github.com/shakacode/sass-resources-loader) ?

Comment: No, because in the gridsome-config doesn't use it..